# Is this is correct way to create list from the array with objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been learning some ES6 recently. I am following Wes Bos "ES6 for everyone" course and wanted to do some scripting myself to test out how much I take in the valuable information.

In this code I am trying to make HTML list from the given variable which is array with the objects inside. So eventually I made this code to work but I am not sure if this is correct way to do it, could you guys take a look at it and tell me what can be fixed and altered for better solution? Thanks

```js
const list = document.createElement('ul');
const students = [{
    name: 'Tom',
    gpa: 4.2,
    course: 'MKDf-16/1',
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Artiom',
    gpa: 2.2,
    course: 'MKDf-16/1',
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alison',
    gpa: 4.8,
    course: 'MKDf-16/2',
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    gpa: 4.1,
    course: 'MKDf-16/5',
    gender: 'male'
  }
];

const output = students.map(student => {
  return `
            ${student.name}'s GPA is ${student.gpa}
        `
});

output.forEach((x, index) => {
  console.log(output[index]);
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.innerHTML = output[index];
  list.appendChild(listItem);
});

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Better to use `const` rather than `let` if you aren't going to reassign the variable in question. Better to assign to an element's `textContent` than its `innerHTML` if you're inserting *text*. Use the *first* argument of the `forEach` function to refer to the element in the array - don't use the `index` unless you have to.

Comment: Code looks fine to me, perhaps you can merge `map` and `forEach`

Comment: not necessary wrong with this code - however CodeReview is better to post than SO tbh...

Comment: For the arrow function you could remove the curly brackets and the return statement: `() => \`${student.name}'s ....\` `

Comment: Thank you guys! I cleaned up my code after these suggestions: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrRerY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const students = [{
    name: 'Tom',
    gpa: 4.2,
    course: 'MKDf-16/1',
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Artiom',
    gpa: 2.2,
    course: 'MKDf-16/1',
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alison',
    gpa: 4.8,
    course: 'MKDf-16/2',
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    gpa: 4.1,
    course: 'MKDf-16/5',
    gender: 'male'
  }
];

const list = document.createElement('ul');
list.innerHTML = students.map(ob => `<li>${ob.name}'s GPA is ${ob.gpa}</li>`).join("");
document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Yes! This the way I was looking for. I remember I saw somewhere a one liner but couldn't find it. Thank you very much, Roko

Comment: What about a student that is named `<script>location="http://thatpornsite.com";</script>` ? :-)

Comment: Haha yeah I know about XSS, in course I am watching, Wes explains about sanitizing the inputs.

Comment: @6502 such student should be escaped in your database, not when such data is returned to the view.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: escaped in the database? Database is about the data and shouldn't even care that you're going to use HTML. You're attacking the problem from the wrong side...

Comment: @6502 so you're saying we should store unsanitized strings into database? I'll keep note. Anyways, createElement or a parser is always a better solution, but you should not be afraid of using innerHTML (or `.html()` in jQuery) when you know what you're doing :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I think the database should contain the real data (what if you need to write some program to extract it and produce a PDF server side for example?). Also with mangled data even queries become problematic as you need to mangle them too as otherwise un-mangled text in the query won't match. In my opinion even the web service should return JSON data with un-mangled database content... presentation is a client problem that simply should us the correct tools (and that is not just taking the JSON content - presumably text - and parse it as HTML).

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way is probably not using `innerHTML` to parse content that includes external data. Much better is to actually create the `<li>` elements and setting their `textContent` instead, avoiding the madness of sanitizing and quoting.

Unfortunately `Javascript` base syntax for creating elements and setting their content is quite ugly and verbose. In my code normally I [end up with an utility function](https://github.com/6502/nolib.js) for that and code like:

```
el("ul", {},
   ...(content.map(x =>
       el("li", {textContent: `${x.name} GPA is ${x.gpa}`}))));
```

can create an `ul` node containing one `li` node for each element in `content` array.

No HTML parsing involved, no quoting or sanitizing needed.